# How to put list of figures/tables after table of contents in revtex4-1

Tags: table-of-contents, revtex

I'm writing my thesis and have written most of it using revtex4-1. When reviewing my notes, I realized I have to have both a list of figures (lof) and list of tables (lot). I'm still rather new to writing papers, but I feel those should go after the table of contents (toc). When I do this, the section numbers over-ride the section headings, see attached picture. The problem I found is with revtex, as switching to article works. I would like to stay with revtex, I'm just not sure how to solve this problem. Any help would be greatly appreciated!
[image: Image of section numbers crowding headings]

Minimal working example:

```
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\listoftables
\newpage
\section{Dummy 1}
\subsection{Dummy 2}
\end{document}
```

Comment: (i) you not provide MWE (Minimal Working Example) but just a fragment of code. (ii) inserting your code fragment in document `book` works as expected, i.e. not produce showed result. (iii) please, extend your code fragment to complete small document, which reproduce your problem.